# Getting HTTP Status 404 - /HelloWorld/ error in eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, spring, jsp, tomcat6

I have created a web Dyanamic project in eclipse indigo just to print Hello World. But I am facing HTTP Status 404 - /HelloWorld/ error in it.

Below is the hello. jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring 3.0 MVC Series: Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>${message}

</body>
</html>
```

Below is code of web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>HelloWorld</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Below is code of index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring 3.0 MVC Series: Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="hello.html">Say Hello</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is Code for HelloWeb-Sevlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd


http://www.springframework.org/schema/context


http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.pkg.controller" />

      <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

My src folder contains co.pkg.controller which have a java file HelloWorldController.java:

```
package com.pkg.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class HelloWorldController {

public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

    String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
    return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
}
}
```

I have Imported below mentioned jars in the Webcontent/Web-Inf/lib folder:

```
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
spring-aop-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
```

I am using JBoss 6.x Runtime Server But the error is:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /HelloWorld/

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /HelloWorld/

description The requested resource (/HelloWorld/) is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
```

Please help me out. I dont know what mistake I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using spring 3.x web mvc. You need to make few changes to your code and configuration. Here are the changes you need to make

1. In HelloWeb-Sevlet.xml, you need to specify

   ```
   <mvc:annotation-deriven/>
   ```

   tag.
2. Place @Controller annotation on top of your controller class and specify RequestMapping on helloWorld() method. Now your class will look as follows

   ```
    package com.pkg.controller;

   import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   @Controller
   public class HelloWorldController {

   @RequestMapping(value="/HelloWorld")
   public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

   String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
   return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
   }
   }
   ```
3. Make sure hello.jsp is there in WEB-INF/jsp/ folder.

Comment: I didnt get how to add the <mvc:annotation-driven/> in my HelloWeb-servlet.xml ? please guide me more on this

Comment: Same as <context:component-scan base-package="com.pkg.controller" /> you need to paste <mvc:annotation-driven/> tag in your HelloWeb-servlet.xml file, That it.

Comment: but it is showing error "the prefix "mvc" for element mvc:annotation-driven is not bound. I pasted <mvc:annotation-driven/> just below the <context:component-scan base-package="com.pkg.controller" />

Comment: I think it will work even if you don't have <mvc:annotation-driven/> tag, just try by removing it

Answer (score 0):

Himanshu,

Don't sweat the annotation-driven entry as it really isn't needed in this particular case.

Raju almost has it right, but the @RequestMapping in the example controller he gave you needs to be:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hello")
```

To run the example, after starting your server type in the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/YourEclipseProjectName/index.jsp
```

Then click the 'Say Hello' link to see the result. If you wish you could also skip that step and directly enter the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/YourEclipseProjectName/hello.html
```

Comment: I am getting this error:
    The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Comment: Himanshu I was able to duplicate your error. You are getting it because of your reference to the libs http://java.sun.com/jsf/core and http://java.sun.com/jsf/html and in your .jsp. They should not be needed, and if you delete them I believe your Spring application will execute. If you make these changes and it runs, please 'accept' one of the answers we gave you.

Comment: I have removed the above 2 statements from the file but still it is not working. what could be the problem. Is my web.xml file is correct?

Comment: The code in your web.xml and servlet both appear correct, however I just noticed your web.xml references spring-servlet while your servlet appears to be called HelloWeb-servlet. Try renaming one or the other. For instance, you could change the two lines in your web.xml which say:                                                   <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
to: <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>

Comment: I have changed the sevlet-name to HelloWeb but the same error occurs i.e Http 404 Description- Requested resource is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem (Tomcat7 Eclipse Kepler) and I *finally* found the answer at http://www.coderanch.com/t/606171/Tomcat/error-requested-resource-Eclipse

Basically index.jsp has to be in the WebContent folder, whilst hello.jsp needs to be in WEB-INF